# Simple regex to match content from a website log

Tags: regex

Having a log with the following lines, I would like to get the following three capturing groups, the ones marked with bold:

> "mywebsite.com:80 1.1.1.1 **u311** - - [26/Sep/2017:11:28:26 +0200]
>   "GET /website&format=json HTTP/1.1" 200 2820 **1s**
>   **"https://mywebsite.com/index.php"** "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64;
>   x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113
>   Safari/537.36" *1/1194130* "

Which are:

- **u311**: It's a user id. Always starts with `u` and have different length (`u32`, `u412`, `u9`), so the regex should match until the next blank space.
- **1s**: It's the loading time of the website. It's always a integer followed by an `s`.
- **https://mywebsite.com/index.php** : The website url, it sould be matched as it has a `https://` at the start.

I'm a bit lost as I'm don't use Regex that much. I've tried the first one by using `^[u][0-9]` with no luck, as that's only matches a string starting with `u` followed by a number.

Here's the Regex if someone wants to try it directly: https://regex101.com/r/so66ku/1

Can someone please tell me how can I match those three capturing groups?

Comment: What environment are you in? There might be better alternatives to regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't know the regex flavor you're using, this solution may not work, but most probably it will:

```
(\bu\d+).*?(\b\d+s\b).*?"(https?:\/\/[^"]*)"
```

will capture the three submatches into different subgroups.

This regex uses [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to make sure that we're at the start/end of a "word" when looking for `u123` or `123s`.

I'm allowing both `http://` and `https://` addresses - if you only want `https://`, just remove the `?` after `https`.

Comment: The matched url seems to be the referrer, I wouldn't assume it to always begin with `https`. I guess making the `s` optional would be good enough

Comment: Ah, that may be - since OP specifically mentioned `https://` I thought that was mandatory.

Comment: Yes, it's always `https`, so no prob.

Comment: Right, I hadn't read that part of the spec. @Avión if your website is linked from other websites, you might get some `http://` referers, although they're rare I guess it doesn't hurt to plan for them. I was thinking about http->https redirection too, but I'm not sure they'd be visible in access logs

Answer (score 1):

you can use the regex

```
(?:u\d+|\d+s|https?:\/\/[a-z.\/]+)
```

see the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/IGMIHx/3)

Comment: Thank you, but that only matches the first two capturing groups, I also need the website url.

Comment: The matched url seems to be the referrer, I wouldn't assume it to always begin with `https`. I guess making the `s` optional would be good enough